# join two tables with date interval 3 days before and 3 days after

Tags: mysql, intervals, datediff, dateinterval

I'm trying to join two tables below

table 1

```
ID    | submit_checkdate
----- | -----------
1     | 2017-07-31
2     | 2017-07-31
3     | 2017-07-31
4     | 2017-07-15
```

table 2

```
ID    | actual_checkdate
----- | ----------
1     | 2017-07-30
2     | 2017-07-25
3     | 2017-08-01
4     | 2017-07-15
```

Expected results

```
ID    | actual_checkdate | submit_checkdate
----- | ----------       | ----------
1     | 2017-07-30       | 2017-07-31
3     | 2017-08-01       | 2017-07-31
4     | 2017-07-15       | 2017-07-15
```

basically, I need the results to show all the actual check dates that are within 3 days before and after the submit check date.

not sure if I should join the tables with the interval or do it in the wherr

Comment: So you need a view with any check date has equal-less difference than 72 hours , right?

Comment: I need a view with any check date that is equal-less 72 hours and equal-more 72 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Add the condition to the join.
           `on actualcheckdate  between dateadd (dd, -3, submitcheckdate) and dateadd (dd, 3, submitcheckdate)`
Or whichever way round it should be

Answer (score 0):

Something like.

`SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.actual_checkdate 
      BETWEEN dateadd (dd, -3, table1.submitcheckdate) 
      AND dateadd (dd, 3, table1.submitcheckdate)`